# How to setup MongoDB with wamp server

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to use MONGO db with my wampserver3.0.6_x64_apache2.4.23_mysql5.7.14_php5.6.25-7.0.10. I have successfully installed MSI(mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.4.3-signed) and also DLL file for the PHP setup on my Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processer. But when i go through the below code

```
echo extension_loaded("mongodb") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";
echo extension_loaded("mysql") ? " mysql loaded\n" : " mysql not loaded\n";
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();

   echo "Connection to database successfully";
   // select a database
   $db = $m->mydb;

   echo "Database mydb selected";
```

its says ---not loaded and -- mysql loaded and Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in C:\wamp64\www\mongotest\conn.php on line 5.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: If you have a 64bit WAMPServer then you need the 64bit Mongo and the 64bit php_mongo.dll

Comment: Alternatively install the 32bit WAMPServer

Comment: Now i have installed wampserver 32 bit, and i have added php_mongo.dll. php_mongo.dll showing in the wampserver extension list. but when i go through the following code to check the services its showing same error msg.                                                                                                        echo extension_loaded("mongodb") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";
echo extension_loaded("mysql") ? " mysql loaded\n" : " mysql not 
its says ---not loaded and -- mysql loaded and Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in